# Does the Server Fault logo remind you vaguely of someone flipping you off?

Tags: discussion, serverfault

Every time I see the Server Fault banner, I see someone giving me the finger. The red line looks like the finger and the dark black bars at the bottom look like knuckles. Anyone else see the same?

Comment: Sorry, that's "not a real question" even by meta standards... And yeah, now I see it, too. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 10):

That's not a bug, that's a feature.

Answer (score 8):

It does now.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 5):

Every time I see the SF logo, I think of an old NES unit:

[alt text http://addictedgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/10/nes.jpg](http://addictedgeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/10/nes.jpg)

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer to this issue ;p

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6677/is-it-just-me-or-does-the-server-fault-icon-look-like-a-nintendo-entertainment-sy